# Font size on R ggpolt2 barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code for barchart:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, y =column2)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge()) + 
         opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='white'))
```

`column1` - names of the bars.

How can I make the font of the names bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the size of x axis labels you should use `axis.text.x=` inside `opts()` (if you use old version of `ggplot2`) or inside `theme()` (starting from `ggplot2` version 0.9.1).

```
+opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=13))

+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=13))
```